# Where can i find buddhist chanting and music?

Tags: reference-request, media

Where can I find chanting or music, inspired by Buddhism?

I would like to have this for my MP3 player so I can remember to practice when not "on the cushion" (cost-free or not, chanting or any type of music inspired by Buddhism, helping us to come back to ourselves or inspiring us to practice, to understand, etc.)

Thank you and kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of videos for you that you might like:

- Thai monks chanting healing mantra: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDCS19EOsrA
- Tibetan monks chanting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P8fNQ0fqSI
- Tibetan monks chanting with singing bowl: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIRJMESl4U8
- Buddhists chants & peace music: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl-m7VrqqaY
- Tibetan Buddhist Chants of Namgyal Monastery: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0IvWX2pmQM

Answer (score 1):

Hi there's an app on Google Play that I downloaded with..i use it a lot.It's not very musical though because it's just a monk chanting with no back ground music.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andromo.dev66510.app68635

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

beautiful chant of the Dhammacakka Sutta by a 3 year old who was a buddhist monk in one of his lifes.

http://www.pirith.org/download/Dhammachakka.mp3

the story about the boy

https://theravadin.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/chanting-in-the-6th-century/